# approve() and sendFrom()

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, metamask

Im trying to run the code below in a smart contract to use as an escrow. calling approve first and calling send from later does nothing to get the tokens into the smart contract, what am I missing here?

```
contract Token {
    function transfer(address _receiver, uint amount) public returns (bool);
    function balanceOf(address receiver)public returns(uint);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool);
}

function withdraw() public {
    tokenAddress = Token(_tokenAddress)
    tokenAddress.approve.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
}

function approve(uint _ammount, address _tokenAddress) public{
    tokenAddress = Token(_tokenAddress)
    tokenAddress.approve(adress(this), _amoount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way `approve` and `transferFrom` are typically used:

1. First, the user (who owns the tokens) calls `approve(contractAddress, amount)` on the token contract.
2. Then, your contract (which now has approval from the user) calls `transferFrom(userAddress, destination, amount)` on the token contract. This actually transfers the tokens.

It's unclear from your question what your contract is supposed to do, so it's hard to make a more specific suggestion.

Comment: can the user call approve directly from my contract? or does it have to call it independently?

My contract is trying to allow the contract to retrive funds from the users wallet, prior approval ofc.
Right now im calling approve by calling the approve function, and then calling transfer from, again from the contract but its not working

Comment: The account that owns the tokens has to call `approve`. (Otherwise contracts could just steal someone's tokens?)

Comment: Wouldnt the user calling the function within the sc work around that?

Comment: No, then the contract is the one calling `approve`.